# Нужен ли laravel Passport для проекта, который предполагает использование своего backend API исключительно в своем же vuejs spa?

Tags: php, laravel

В проекте предполагается, что серверная часть с фронтом будут взаимодействовать исключительно посредством `JSON`

Нужен ли `laravel Passport` для проекта, который предполагает использование своего `backend API` исключительно в своем же `vuejs spa` по сути нужна самая обычная авторизация, но чтобы юзер узнавался не по сессии, а по токену, переданному в параметрах. Чем может быть плоха такая реализация аутентификации? https://gistlog.co/JacobBennett/090369fbab0b31130b51

Comment: Laravel [API Authentication (Passport)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport) как раз и нужен для авторизации в API по токену.

Comment: Вы спрашиваете чем плох OAuth?

Comment: когда еще не было passport, был и сейчас есть TokenGuard, который должен узнавать пользователя по переданному api_token

Comment: 'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

Comment: /config/auth.php:44